# How do I get my pc to add my AV receiver to it so I can use it for sound ouput? 

Tags: 11.10, sound, hdmi

How do I get my pc to add my AV receiver to it so I can use it for sound ouput? I am trying to get sound from my pc that is connected to my av receiver. Do I need to load a driver or something? I have AV receiver and my pc in connected to it using HDMI and AV receiver to TV HDMI. I am not getting sound out of my PC to my AV receiver but video is getting to TV.

Comment: To the OP. You need to be specific about what AV equipment you have and how you intend to attach it to your machine. if you are speaking of the sound>out to the AV you would want to include RCA jacks? Stereo?

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: Do you have sound via headphones / external speakers?

Answer (score 1):

Does the TV support sound? Check if you can get sound out with the TV disconnected from the AV Receiver.

While my setup is a bit different (Computer:HDMI --> AV Reciever:HDMI --> TV:DVI) I've learned that the EDID the PC saw was that of the TV. As the TV had DVI and not HDMI, the PC didn't think sound was supported and only sent video. Thanks to the drivers not having an override function (nVidia, Windows) I had to create a custom cable between the AV and TV that blocked the EDID of the TV. Thus the EDID of the AV was instead sent to the Computer and I got my sound **and** video.

(The cable was a 6" HDMI with its data lines cut :P its a good SONY AV reciever, so the computer still allows HDCP playback! but YMMV)